# Who was behind the R3S6 droid from the Republic's side?

Tags: star-wars, tv, the-clone-wars

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, R2-D2 was lost in an accident. Anakin was allotted a new droid -- R3-S6, which was an enemy spy (probably, belonged to Grevious). R2-D2 destroyed it in the end, so there wasn't any chance to decode its memory.

Palpatine wasn't clearly involved because the droid was trying to kill Anakin:

- It activated the separatist droids in the garbage.
- It detached Anakin's ship from the hyperdrive ring when Anakin ordered it to engage hyperdrive near enemy fleet.
- It started the beacon on Anakin's ship to draw attention from the enemy.

While the inspection results were never shown, who really brought that nasty droid to Anakin?

Answer (score 2):

It was General Grievous who "sent" the droid to harm Anakin, and it was his own idea.

All the astromech droids are prepared by Industrial Automaton and handed over to the Republic for their help.

However at some point of time Grievous stole some droids and **ordered** to reprogram them to work as spies. And silently put them back before Industrial Automation or Jedi or Republic realize that. After losing R2 D2 in battle of Bothawui R3-S6 was handed over to Anakin following advice from Master Yoda and Mace Windu.

If you have watched the episode you can see that R3-S6 was reporting directly to Grievous. And the whole mess was master plan of General Grievous. From [this](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R3-S6) Wookieepedia article

> An R3-series astromech droid, R3-S6 was manufactured by Industrial
>   Automaton on the planet Nubia around the time of the Clone Wars.
>   While most R3-series astromech droids had clear-transparent domes,
>   some droids—such as R3-S6—were shipped with salvaged R2-series domes;
>   during the Clone Wars, the Galactic Republic needed droid units
>   available for purchase even with such minor defects. In 21
>   BBY, the Confederate General Grievous hired agents to steal an
>   astromech droid from Industrial Automaton on Nubia. The
>   agents took R3-S6 to the planet Milagro, and inside a Republic
>   base, it was reprogrammed to become a spy for Grievous.

Even you can read the synopsis of the episode "Duel of the Droids" on [this](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Duel_of_the_Droids) Wookieepedia article.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned Grevious in question.. You have just repeated it. You have ignored the republic's side part. Grevious reprogrammed few droids (not all). And, it can't be coincidence that the reprogrammed droid was chosen by Yoda and Windu.

Comment: Sorry if the answer did sound harsh. As mentioned above yoda and windu sent the droids without any knowledge about the droid's reprogramming, (IMHO) if they have it, they have acted against Grievous or even R3S6 is not sent to the anakin. So IMO, yes it is a coincidence that yoda and windu blindly sent Goldie to anakin...

Comment: Do you have any canonical source to confirm Yoda & Windu picked Goldie?

Comment: @SachinShekhar If you read the link posted about r3s6, it's ambiguous to who on the republic side did it. 'The agents took R3-S6 to the planet Milagro,[10] and inside a Republic base,[5] it was reprogrammed to become a spy for Grievous.[10]' [5] refers to the swcw char guide and [10] refers to the decoded episode of the duel of the droids. Who the agents are, is not answered. The intro quote from ahsoka happens at ~ 7:40 in to duel of the droids.  That is all they mention in either episode.

Comment: @Mike I don't believe Wookipedia. I am looking for answers from books etc too. If someone has typed those words after watching that episode, I am not really going to believe it..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Then go watch the episode. I can verify that there is no mention of who/what/where on the republic side in the dvd versions. I can also so that unless it's relatively new, there is nothing else to add to it other than 'they'. not every detail is fleshed out.

Comment: @Mike The full season is in my mind.. That's why I am looking for back etc based answer. Wookipedia says "no" means someone has typed just after watching episodes..